# Regular expression to capture start of directories and websites

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to come up with a regular expression to capture instances of `C:\` or `H:/`, etc. inside a string, but I am having issues. I have tried (in my Java code) several variations of

```
line = line.replaceAll("[A-Z]:[/\\\\]", " ");
```

However it does not seem to work. I also need to match `https://`, so would it be possible to generalize this to match a group of letters of indiscriminate length and capitalization, followed by a colon, followed by either `\`, `/`, `\\`, or `//`?

Comment: Capture or replace ? Please post some examples of string to capture.

Comment: Your regex looks OK for ``C:\`` and `H:/`. What problems exactly are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?i)[a-z]:(\\\\|/)|https?://", " ");
```

---

will replace the strings below with    (space), case insensitive:

```
c:\
d:/
http://
https://
```

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
[a-z]:(\\\\|/)|https?://

Options: Case insensitive; 

Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[a-z]:(\\\\|/)»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «[a-z]»
   Match the character “:” literally «:»
   Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\\\\|/)»
      Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\\\\»
         Match the backslash character «\\»
         Match the backslash character «\\»
      Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «/»
         Match the character “/” literally «/»
Or match this alternative (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «https?://»
   Match the character string “http” literally (case insensitive) «http»
   Match the character “s” literally (case insensitive) «s?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character string “://” literally «://»


Insert the character “ ” literally « »
```

Comment: Do I need to add in an "or" for instances of `http` over `https` to make your expression `replaceAll("(?im)[a-z]:(\\\\|/)|https?://|http?://", " ")`?

Comment: No, the`s?` makes the `s` optional, so it will match `http` or `https`. I've updated my a with an expanation

Comment: Your pattern is not capturing c:\, but c:\\. Remove 2 `\\`.

Comment: No @DanielDutra, it's java and the backslash needs 2 escapes. [Regular Expressions, Literal Strings and Backslashes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know this particularity.

Comment: @DanielDutra sem "probrema" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern works for all four cases: `[A-Z]:[/\\]|https?://`

It captures an Uppercase letter followed by `:`, then followed by either a `\` or `/`. Or captures the letters `http`, followed or not by an `s`, followed by `://`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/oH1aW7/1